# Ventana secundaria dentro de una ventana principal con Python y Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, popup

¿Cómo hago para que una ventana secundaria que creé dentro de una ventana principal no se vaya hacia atrás, sino que se mantenga sobre la ventana principal hasta que yo haga click en el botón cerrar?

Quisiera que fuera igual a como funciona una ventana emergente (popup), la cual no permite acceder a la ventana principal, hasta que se cierre dicho popup.

Estoy usando Python y Tkinter.
-Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido! En StackOverflow las preguntas que no contienen ejemplos con el código que has intentado y la traza de error no suelen ser bien recividas, ya que no demuestran investigación previa. Suena a "Tengo este problema, resolvedlo".

Answer (score -1):

Mediante la llamada al método 'grab_set' se desactivan los eventos en la ventana principal, es decir que hasta que el usuario no cierre el diálogo la ventana principal aparecerá inactiva. Un ejemplo de su uso podría ser:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror, showinfo
nombre = ""
lenguaje = ""


class Nueva(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.mostrar_campos()

    def mostrar_campos(self):
        self.master.title("Nueva ventana")
        self.nombre = tk.Label(self, text="Nombre y apellidos: ")
        self.nombre.pack(side="left")
        self.nombre = tk.Entry(self)
        self.nombre.pack(side="left")

        self.lenguaje = tk.Label(self, text="Lenguaje de programación preferido: ")
        self.lenguaje.pack(side="left")
        self.lenguaje = tk.Entry(self)
        self.lenguaje.pack(side="left")

        self.button_guardar = tk.Button(self, text="Guardar", fg="green", command=self.actualizar_datos)
        self.button_guardar.pack(side="left")

        self.button_cancelar = tk.Button(self, text="Cancelar", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button_cancelar.pack(side="left")

    def actualizar_datos(self):
        nombre = self.nombre.get()
        lenguaje_text = self.lenguaje.get()
        nombre_lenguaje_requerido = (nombre.isspace() or nombre == '') and (lenguaje_text.isspace()
                                                                            or lenguaje_text == '')

        nombre_requerido = (nombre.isspace() and not lenguaje_text.isspace()) or (nombre == '' and lenguaje_text != '')

        lenguaje_requerido = (not nombre.isspace() and lenguaje_text.isspace()) or (nombre != ''
                                                                                    and lenguaje_text == '')

        mensaje = "Debe ingresar su nombre y lenguaje de programación preferido" if nombre_lenguaje_requerido else "Debe ingresar su nombre" if nombre_requerido else "Debe ingresar su lenguaje de programación preferido" if lenguaje_requerido else None
        if mensaje:
            showerror("Campos requeridos", mensaje, parent=self)
        else:
            print("Nombre y apellidos:", nombre)
            print("Lenguaje de programación preferido:", lenguaje_text)
            showinfo("Acción exitosa", "Los datos se han guardado correctamente", parent=self)
            self.master.destroy()


class Principal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.mostrar_campos()

    def mostrar_campos(self):
        self.boton = tk.Button(self, text="Crear nueva", command=self.crear_nueva)
        self.boton.pack(side="top")

    def crear_nueva(self):
        raiz2 = tk.Toplevel()
        n = Nueva(master=raiz2)
        n.grab_set()


tk_raiz = tk.Tk()
principal = Principal(master=tk_raiz)
principal.master.title("Ventana principal")

principal.mainloop()
```

En este código, lo que permite que no haya eventos de ratón o teclado que se envíen a la ventana principal cuando está abierta la "Nueva ventana", es:

```
n.grab_set()
```

Mientras que para evitar que se realice algún evento en la "Nueva ventana", cuando se muestra el error de "Campos requeridos" o el mensaje de "Acción exitosa", es poner en la opción "parent" del messagebox:

```
parent=self
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me fue muy útil y pude resolver mi problema.